# PimCore X Not Loading

Tags: apache2, pimcore

I've been following the guide found here, https://unixcop.com/how-to-install-pimcore-on-ubuntu-20-04/, to install the PimCore X version from scratch on a fresh server.

However, after going through all of the steps and firing up the initial home page, I get the profiler complaining about a number of 404 errors for resources that it cannot find within the /_wdt/ folder, with the profiler never loading.

The admin section of PimCore cannot be loaded either, it comes up with a big 404 error, so I'm guessing that the router isn't working properly. Looking into the log files for both PimCore and Apache, there isn't anything useful to be found.

I've tried to install PimCore several times, each with the same result.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the .htaccess file within the /public/ folder wasn't being installed with the fresh install. The .htaccess file contents can be found here, https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Apache_Configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Best way to install Pimcore are using docker.
You can read it on github page https://github.com/pimcore/skeleton
All that you need is install docker.
You can do it from this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04